# iOS development - Is including iPhone 4s compulsory?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swift5

I'm currently building UI these days.
The problem is that iPhone 4s has such a small screen, I can't put UI components into it properly.

How can I exclude outdated phones like iPhone 4s when I launch the app?

Comment: iPhone 4S max iOS version is 9.3.6. Developing for iOS 10+ only should be sufficient to cover most cases and excludes it. Even higher versions depending on your requirements.

Comment: I would actually suggest targeting iOS 12 or even 13 from the get go. There's very small amount of users on older iOS versions, so it's not worth the effort supporting those versions.

Comment: Thanks u guys for kind answers!

Comment: Just be aware of iPhone SE (1st Gen) that might cause you some issue ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that'd be very unusual these days. iPhone 4s only runs up to iOS 9, so simply target iOS 10.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, there is no support from Apple for this kind of thing. But you can do something like detecting whether the user's device is an iPhone SE and if so show a full screen alert saying "App is not supported for this device" and block the UI (which is not recommended unless it's required).

**Just a thought:**
If you are lucky to find out one device capability which distinguish iPhone SE, you can set that to value in **UIDeviceRequiredCapabilities** key in info.plist.

Example: Adding an item to UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in your Info.plist with the requirement of "bluetooth-le" should limit your app to iPhone 4S/5 and iPad 3, 4 and mini. You could also throw in a "camera-flash" requirement to limit the app to iPhones only, should you need that.

Another thing you can do is check for iOS versions. As you may know, some of the older phones cannot support newer iOS versions, so you can check for iOS version and if it is greater than your desired version, you can run the application or limit it in the store.

*More info:*

[Device Compatibility Matrix](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013599-CH17-SW1)

[Maximum supported versions of Apple Devices](https://everyi.com/by-capability/maximum-supported-ios-version-for-ipod-iphone-ipad.html)

Comment: "App is not supported for this device" will get your app rejected by Apple.

Comment: Never knew that before, I would read the documentation you had recommended. Thank you !